# Math question partial derivatives

Tags: derivatives

I have to find the $\partial^2 z/\partial x \partial y$ of $z=e^{xy}$. I know how to find  $\partial^2 z/\partial x^2$ which by the way is $y^2 e^{xy}$ but not this one...can you give me a little hint?
and please tell me how to find this type of "power" partial derivatives,like $\partial^3z/\partial x^2 \partial y$..

Answer (score 2):

Hint : $$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)$$

For all you others "types of power partial derivatives" as you say, simply split them.

Example : $$\frac{\partial^n z}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2 \partial x_3 \dots \partial x_n} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\left(\dots\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_n}\right)\right)\right)\right) $$